# How can I set LinearGradientBrush as the background for of ContentPages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, lineargradientbrush

How can I add `LinearGradientBrush` as `ContentPage.Background` in `App.xaml`'s `ResourceDictionary`? My code pasted below:

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="LightBlue"
                  Offset="0.1" />
    <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue"
                  Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LinearGradientBrush is a preview concept,don't forgget to add below codes in your `App.xaml.cs`.

```
Device.SetFlags(new string[] {"Brush_Experimental" });
```

and add below to the `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style  TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="LightBlue"
              Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue"
              Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Ahh, I've found out that I've added `Device.SetFlags` below the `InitializeComponent()` `App.xaml.cs`, this line should be on top.